# How can I remove small arrow icon in right side of FlatList in React-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm newbie in React-native. I wanna know how I can eliminate the arrow icon in my flat List?
 here is a screenshot of the FlatList:

[image: 10]

And Here is my code:

```
<List containerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'column-reverse', borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }} >
   <FlatList 
       data={this.state.record} 
       keyExtractor={((item, index) => "itemNo-" + index)}
       renderItem={({item}) => (
       <ListItem
           roundAvatar
           onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Meaning', {data: (item.word_english +'\n' + item.word_arabic)} ); }}
           title={item.word_english}
           containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
        /> )}
      />
</List>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you post the code of the "ListItem" Component?

Comment: @Nino9612 I don't get you! I have done it! You mean something else?

Comment: You havent posted the code for the "ListItem" Component. You are using it inside the flatlist as the list item element. We need to get the code from this component because its cointaing the icon you want to hide. But the answer from @Andrew solved it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `react-native-elements` version `0.19.1`. Due to the fact that `roundAvatar` was deprecated in [version 1](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/blog/#listitem).

To hide the chevron all you need to do is use the `hideChevron` prop. You can see this in the [documentation](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/lists.html#hidechevron) for `0.19.1`.

```
<ListItem
  ...
  hideChevron={true}
/>
```

In `react-native-elements` version `1+` the [chevron](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html#chevron) is automatically hidden.